# jQuery - how to loop remove only certain child nodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing

Say I have something like this:

```
<p>
 <br><br>
 <img id='unique'>
 <br>
</p>
```

I want jQuery to loop through the p tag and remove all the line break tags. Keep in mind I have to find the p element by first finding the image element which is the only element that has a unique identifier.

I tried some loops and looked in the docs but don't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#unique").parent().find("br").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
   $("#unique").parent('p').find('br').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can select the #unique and the closest() p tag using the following

```
$('#unique').closest('p'))
```

or,

```
$('#unique').parent()
```

Then to select the br, you can chain any of the above:

```
$('#unique').parent().find('br')
```

For deleting, the complete code is:

```
$('#unique').parent().find('br').remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("p").each(function(){
     $(this).find("br").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

See it here http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/EqVf5/

```
if ($('p').has('#unique')) {
    $('p').find('br').remove();
}​
```